# Multiple table record delete query incorrect syntax error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database. I want to delete multiple table records in a single query using `id`.

But I am getting an

> Incorrect Syntax error ','

I know my query might be wrong. I need a correct query or solution for this.

I have 4 tables: `Products`, `ProductVideos`, `Pictures` and `Inventory`. I    need to delete all the records in a same product id in a single query.

My query is:

```
DELETE FROM Products, ProductVideos, Pictures, Inventory 
USING Products 
INNER JOIN ProductVideos 
INNER JOIN Pictures 
INNER JOIN Inventory 
WHERE Products.Id = ProductVideos.ProductId 
  AND ProductVideos.ProductId = Pictures.ProductId 
  AND Pictures.ProductId = Inventory.ProductId 
  AND Products.Id = 1
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an SQL Server query? `USING`, inner joins without `ON` predicates, etc.? Please provide more concise information on what you want to do, more schema information about your tables and some examples of data (input and expected outputs).

Answer (score 1):

Your question was wrong.

I think you should use this solution:

```
delete from [dbo].[Inventory] 
where ProductID in (select Id from Products where Id = 1)

delete from [dbo].[Pictures] 
where ProductID in (select Id from Products where Id = 1)

delete from [dbo].[ProductVideos] 
where ProductID in (select Id from Products where Id = 1)

delete from [dbo].[Products] 
where Id = 1
```

Comment: And the point is: you **cannot** delete from four tables with a **single** query - you need four separate queries

Comment: To add to **@marc_s**'s comment, what you could do is wrap them into a transaction. This way either all of them would delete at once or none would.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete multiple table's data in single query like this in SQL Server.
You have to delete data from each table one by one.

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 1

DELETE I 
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN ProductVideos PV ON P.Id = PV.ProductId
INNER JOIN Pictures PC ON PC.ProductID = PV.ID
INNER JOIN Inventory I ON I.ProductId = PC.ProductId
WHERE P.Id = @id

DELETE PC 
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN ProductVideos PV ON P.Id = PV.ProductId
INNER JOIN Pictures PC ON PC.ProductID = PV.ID
WHERE P.Id = @id

DELETE PV 
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN ProductVideos PV ON P.Id = PV.ProductId
WHERE P.Id = @id

DELETE P 
FROM Products P
WHERE P.Id = @id
```

While deleting it is very important to keep it in mind the order of tables and will be better if you use TRANSACTION in query.